# Set 'parameters' annotation in NelmioApiDocBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosrestbundle, api-doc

I create an API RESTfull using Symfony2.1 with FOSRESTBundle and I am using [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) to generate automatic documentation.

I have a PUT request in which the user should send one parameter, but I don't need to create a Form for this purpose. All works perfectly but when I generate the documentation I don't know how to add this parameter to the documentation because I don't have a 'input' form.

I tried this but seems doesn't work:

```
 /**
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  description="description",
 *  statusCodes={
 *         200="Success",
 *         400="Bad request"},
 *  parameters={
 *         {"name"="parameter_name", "dataType"="integer"}
 *  }
 * )
 ...
```

In the documentation of [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) I didn't see any solution for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use filters key instead of parameters

```
 * filters={
 *     {"name"="parameter_name", "dataType"="integer"},
 * },
```

Comment: Yes, I am using this now, but filters are not the same as parameters... Is there any posibility to use parameters? Thanks!!!